# How to duplicate a tab in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, clone, tabs, duplicate

Is it possible to clone/duplicate tab in Firefox?

Basicaly, the other **new** tab should contain the same history of the tab I'm trying to clone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two possible ways that I've found out:

### Using the History

1. Right clicking on the back/forward buttons of the browser which will open the history of the page. (You can also do the next step directly on the arrows, but if you opened the history you get to choose which page to open from the history, instead of opening directly the previous or next one)
2. - Press (and keep pressing) the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button and click on one of pages in the history.
   - Click on one of the pages with the mouse's middle click button.
3. Now, after doing any of the steps in the second point, it will open a new tab with the same history of the old tab, and the starting page will be the page you've chosen from the history.

### Wihout using the History

If you try to drag and drop the tab as if you were re-arranging it, keep holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button before releasing the mouse button while dragging the tab.
This will do the same as above except that you can get to choose where to clone the tab in the tab-bar, and the starting page of the cloned tab is the same as the original one.

*Thought I'd share my simple but interesting findings*

Comment: Ctrl + Drag n drop is excellent!  Note that the answer suggests that you have to press Ctrl between drag and release, but it also works if you keep Ctrl pressed the whole time and then drag.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know Dan's methods. Here are some additional ways:

- simply middleclick the refresh button
- drag the icon on the left of the address (the "i" in circle or the lock) to the tab bar
- doubleclick the address to select it whole, then move the mouse a little (to not register a triple click) and click again and hold to drag it to the tab bar

Comment: Just a small note, last 2 points don't actually duplicate the tab. The back/forward history won't exist in the newly opened tab. Though, the middle click on the refresh button is a nice and quick way to do it.